# Link Tagging Username to Profile

Tags: php, laravel, function, preg-match

At the moment I link every word from the body of the post that follows a @ to a profile. The following code is in the post model. The problem is, it will also be linked if the profile does not exist.

How can I make sure that the profile exists and only then link to the profile?

And if the user has a privacy of 3, the profile should be linked to the ID and not to the username. But the Auth::user() can see his username.

```
<?php

protected function replaceUserNames($body)
{
    preg_match_all('/@(\w+)/', $body, $users);
    if (!isSet($users[1])) {
        return $body;
    }
    $userList = Collect($users[1]);
    foreach ($userList->unique() as $user) {
        $body = str_replace('@' . $user, 
            '<a href="/profile/' . $user . '">@' . $user . '</a>', $body);
    }

    return $body;
}
```

Comment: extract username, then look up profile, only if exists, add link

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: in the foreach loop check they exist before linking.

Comment: Can you give me an example where I have to insert the foreach loop?